# ViewExpiredException redirect not working with JSTL tag forEach in view

Tags: jsf, jstl

**Environment:**
I have an EAR application with WildFly 10.0.0.Final. It has one module for the web application which is based on JSF Mojarra 2.2.12-jbossorg-2 20150729-1131 (using PrimeFaces 6 for the UI and Omnifaces 2.5.1 for additional utilities).

**Use Case:**
My Problem is around view expiration. I simplified my app to a small bean/view showcase which contains the problem. The use case is pretty simple: if the view is expired and the user triggers some action, he should be redirected to the view expired page. I am using the Omnifaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler for this.

**Problem:**
The redirect on view expiration is working in nearly all cases. But it is not working anymore as soon as I use the JSTL tag `<c:forEach/>` in my view. Then, the HTTP Request simply has a Status *(failed)* in my Chrome Dev Tools and nothing happens.

The following Bean/View combination shows the problem:

**View: text.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head id="head">
  <title>Test</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
  <h:form>
    <p:commandButton action="#{TestBean.throwError()}" value="Throw" update=":test"/>
  </h:form>

  <h:panelGroup id="test">
    Test
  </h:panelGroup>

  <c:forEach items="#{TestBean.list}" var="item">
    #{item.toString()}
  </c:forEach>

  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Invalidate session"
       onclick="$.get('#{request.contextPath}/invalidatesession?#{now.time}', alert('Session invalidated!'))"/>
  </p>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Bean: Test.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;

@ViewScoped
@Named(value = "TestBean")
public class Test implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6513676596620667863L;

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        this.list.add("aaaaa");
        this.list.add("bbbbb");
        this.list.add("ccccc");
    }

    public void throwError()
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("bla");
    }

    public List<String> getList()
    {
        return this.list;
    }
}
```

It's pretty much the FullAjaxExceptionHandler Show Case of Omnifaces with the JSTL tag `<c:forEach/>`. As soon as I remove it from my View, everyhting works fine.